# What prompts the palace extension event?

Tags: civilization, civilization-for-networks

Back in the day, [Civilization (I)](https://civilization.fandom.com/wiki/Palace_(Civ1)) and its 1995 remake Civilization for Networks ([CivNet](https://civilization.fandom.com/wiki/CivNet)) did have an event that triggered occasionally where you would add an improvement to your palace. The very first time the screen would look like this:

[image]
However, I never understood what did trigger this event, only that it was a very cool thing and I loved when it happened.

Under what conditions did the people "spontaneously decide" to make an addition to your palace in those old Civ games?

Comment: I always assumed general happyness triggers this event, not unlike the "golden age" of later Civs. But now I realize I have no basis for this assumption

Comment: I thought it was when your score went up... at the end of the game you can see what your score was.